# How can I find first variation

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-derivative

I have a functional:

$$F=\int_0^l \left[ V(h)+{1\over 2}\left(h_x\right)^2 \right] dx$$

where $V(h)$ is just a function of $h=h(x,t)$, and $h$ subjects to periodic boundary conditions

$$h[0,t]=h[l,t]$$
$$h_x[0,t]=h_x[l,t]$$
$$h_{xx}[0,t]=h_{xx}[l,t]$$
How can I obtain its **first variation**

$$\frac {\delta F}{\delta h}=?$$

I have tried as follows:

Let $F\equiv\int f(h,h_x) dx $, $x\in [0,l]$, and a small perturbation $\delta h=\epsilon \eta (x)$ subjects to $\eta (0)=0, \eta (l)=0$
$$\delta F=F(h+\delta h)-F(h)=F(h+\epsilon \eta)-F(h)=\int f(h+\epsilon \eta,h_x+\epsilon \eta_x)dx-\int f(h,h_x)dx= \int\left[f(h,h_x)+ {\partial f\over \partial h}\epsilon \eta+{\partial f\over \partial h_x}\epsilon \eta_x \right]dx+O(\epsilon^2)-\int f(h,h_x)dx=\epsilon\int\left[{\partial f\over \partial h} \eta+{\partial f\over \partial h_x} \eta_x \right]dx+O(\epsilon^2) $$

Thus at leading order of $\epsilon$,

$$\frac {\delta F}{\delta h}=\frac {\delta F}{\epsilon \eta}=\frac {1}{\eta} \int\left[{\partial f\over \partial h} \eta+{\partial f\over \partial h_x} \eta_x \right]dx=\frac {1}{\eta} \int\left[{dV\over dh} \eta+h_x \eta_x \right]dx=$$

$$ \frac {1}{\eta} \int \eta [\frac {dV}{dh}-h_{xx}]dx=??$$

Then, how can I get the finial result which should contain $\frac{dV}{dh}$ and $h_{xx}$. Can I eliminate $\eta$? Any one can give me a hint? If you can find some mistakes, it will be also appreciated!

Comment: integrate the second part in the last integral by part

Comment: @tired, Please see my updated post(only the last step). I have move forward one step based on your hint. But how can I remove $\eta (x)$ from the expression, because it is just an arbitrary perturbation, but a function of $x$...